# How can I add a value to a property in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have the following Object:

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    ......
    ......
    tokens:{
       token: {
           type: String,
           required: true   
       }
     }
```

Then I generate a token and try to add the value in property tokens.token like below

```
//generated token
const token = jwt.sign({_id : user._id.toString()}, process.env.JWT_TOKEN_SECRET,{
            expiresIn: process.env.JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN
        })

//add value in property
user.tokens.token = token

console.log(user.tokens)
```

The value that I take is

```
[]
```

I also tried

```
user.tokens['token'] = token
```

But I get the same results.

How can I add a value in an Object property?

Comment: Try

user = JSON.parse(user);
user.tokens.token = token

Comment: Mongoose documents are special, and cannot be altered this way. You first need to convert `user` to a plain Object, using `const userObj = user.toObject();` And then, you can do `userObj.tokens.token = token; console.log(userObj);` [Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)